# Closing an App on Mac using Ruby code

Tags: ruby, macos

I can open an app using

```
file_to_open = "/Applications/Revu.app"
system %{open "#{file_to_open}"}
```

But I'm not sure how to write the code to close it using Ruby. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shell out to AppleScript:

```
system %{ osascript -e 'tell application "Revu" to quit'}
```